# Drop down to have default selected the first element of the list in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic list to display on dropdown. But always the first element of the list should be selected by default on gui and later on user can select any other.
When I am trying to display the first element of the list in my drop down, that element repeated in the list and if user select any other element then that element is being repeated. Below is my code.

***html code:***

```
<select class="form-control" name="settingTabs" id="settingTabs" ng-model="mData.selectedTabName" ng-change="selectTab()" ng-init="mData.selectedTabName = mData.tabList[0].settingTabName" ng-options="settingTabs.settingTabName for settingTabs in mData.tabList">
    <option value="">{{mData.selectedTab}}</option>
</select>
```

***js code:***

```
$scope.selectTab = function(){
    var x = $scope.mData.tabList.indexOf($scope.mData.selectedTabName);
    $scope.mData.selectedTab = $scope.mData.tabList[x].settingTabName;
}
```

Need help here so I can have only the list to display in dropdown and by default first element should be selected displayed from that list.

Comment: I assume you're talking about `handlebars` here. Where's the proper tag?

Answer (score 0):

I myself got an answer so thought of posting this too. Since angular provide default option for drop down, so make that ng-if="false" will work here.

```
<option value="" ng-if="false">{{mData.selectedTab}}</option>
```